# "Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid."

Tags: vb.net

I keep getting the error `Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid`. I know that it means i am trying to convert nothing into a integer and the compiler doesn't like that, but i can't find where in my program because it only happens when I build my program and not in debug. Sorry I can't give more information.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Public Class frmindex
'Variables
Dim addworld As String
Dim root As String
Dim allownether As String
Dim pvp As String
Dim whitelist As String
Dim spawnmonsters As String
Dim onlinemode As String
Dim spawnanimals As String
Dim bit As String
Dim allowflight As String
Dim launch As String
Dim serverfile As String
Dim safeserverfile As String
Dim ram As ULong
Dim halfram As Integer
Dim serverapplication As String
Dim filter As String

Private Sub frmindex_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Finds Half of the ram of the computer and -1
    ram = My.Computer.Info.TotalPhysicalMemory
    halfram = ((ram / "1,048,576") / "2") - "1"
    nudram.Maximum = halfram

    If nudram.Value = "" Or "1024" Then
        nudram.Value = halfram
    End If



    If txbserverfile.Text = "" Then
        txbserverfile.Text = CurDir() + "\" + serverapplication
    End If
    If cmbserverapplication.Text = "Exe Server" Then
        serverapplication = "minecraft_server.exe"
        lblram.Visible = False
        nudram.Visible = False
        filter = "Exe Server|*.exe|All Files|*.*"
    ElseIf cmbserverapplication.Text = "Jar Server" Then
        serverapplication = "minecraft_server.jar"
        lblram.Visible = True
        nudram.Visible = True
        filter = "Jar Server|*.jar|All Files|*.*"
    ElseIf cmbserverapplication.Text = "Bukkit Server" Then
        serverapplication = "craftbukkit-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
        lblram.Visible = False
        nudram.Visible = False
        filter = "Bukkit Server|*.jar|All Files|*.*"
    End If

    If nudviewdistance.Text = "" Then
        nudviewdistance.Text = "10"
    End If
    'finds load files



    If cmbserverapplication.Text = "Exe Server" Then
        lblram.Visible = False
        nudram.Visible = False
    ElseIf cmbserverapplication.Text = "Jar Server" Then
        lblram.Visible = True
        nudram.Visible = True
    ElseIf cmbserverapplication.Text = "Bukkit Server" Then
        lblram.Visible = False
        nudram.Visible = False
    End If

    'Checks if save folder exists if not creates one
    If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(root + "\setting")) Then
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(root + "\setting")
    End If
    'loads world settings
    If File.Exists(root + "\setting\world.txt") Then
        For Each line As String In File.ReadLines(root + "\setting\world.txt")
            If line.Length <> 0 Then
                cmbworld.Items.Add(line)
            End If
        Next line
    End If
    'loads ip
    If File.Exists(root + "\setting\ip.txt") Then
        For Each line As String In File.ReadLines(root + "\setting\ip.txt")
            If line.Length <> 0 Then
                cmbip.Items.Add(line)
            End If
        Next line
    End If

    'loads levelseed
    If File.Exists(root + "\setting\levelseed.txt") Then
        For Each line As String In File.ReadLines(root + "\setting\levelseed.txt")
            If line.Length <> 0 Then
                cmblevelseed.Items.Add(line)
            End If
        Next line
    End If

    If File.Exists(root + "\banned-players.txt") Then
        For Each line As String In File.ReadLines(root + "\banned-players.txt")
            If line.Length <> 0 Then
                cmbbannedplayers.Items.Add(line)
            End If
        Next line
    End If

    If File.Exists(root + "\banned-ips.txt") Then
        For Each line As String In File.ReadLines(root + "\banned-ips.txt")
            If line.Length <> 0 Then
                cmbbannedips.Items.Add(line)
            End If
        Next line
    End If

    If File.Exists(root + "\ops.txt") Then
        For Each line As String In File.ReadLines(root + "\ops.txt")
            If line.Length <> 0 Then
                cmbops.Items.Add(line)
            End If
        Next line
    End If

    If File.Exists(root + "\white-list.txt") Then
        For Each line As String In File.ReadLines(root + "\white-list.txt")
            If line.Length <> 0 Then
                cmbwhitelist.Items.Add(line)
            End If
        Next line
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnlaunch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnlaunch.Click
    If System.IO.Directory.Exists(root + "\setting") = True Then
    Else
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(root + "\setting")
    End If
    Dim sbcmbworld As New StringBuilder()

    For Each item As Object In cmbworld.Items
        sbcmbworld.AppendFormat("{0} {1}", item, Environment.NewLine)
    Next
    Dim cmbworldsave As String = root + "\setting\world.txt"
    If System.IO.File.Exists(cmbworldsave) = True Then
    Else
        System.IO.File.Create(root + "\setting\world.txt").Dispose()
    End If
    Dim worldWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(cmbworldsave)
    worldWriter.Write(sbcmbworld.ToString()) 'Use the stringbuilder here
    worldWriter.WriteLine()
    worldWriter.Close()

    Dim sbcmbip As New StringBuilder()

    For Each item As Object In cmbworld.Items
        sbcmbip.AppendFormat("{0} {1}", item, Environment.NewLine)
    Next
    Dim cmbipsave As String = root + "\setting\ip.txt"
    If System.IO.File.Exists(cmbworldsave) = True Then
    Else
        System.IO.File.Create(root + "\setting\ip.txt").Dispose()
    End If

    Dim ipwriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(cmbipsave)
    ipwriter.Write(sbcmbip.ToString()) 'Use the stringbuilder here
    ipwriter.WriteLine()
    ipwriter.Close()

    Dim sbcmblevelseed As New StringBuilder()

    For Each item As Object In cmbworld.Items
        sbcmbip.AppendFormat("{0} {1}", item, Environment.NewLine)
    Next
    Dim cmblevelseedsave As String = root + "\setting\levelseed.txt"
    If System.IO.File.Exists(cmbworldsave) = True Then
    Else
        System.IO.File.Create(root + "\setting\levelseed.txt").Dispose()
    End If
    Dim levelseedWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(cmbipsave)
    levelseedWriter.Write(sbcmblevelseed.ToString()) 'Use the stringbuilder here
    levelseedWriter.WriteLine()
    levelseedWriter.Close()

    Dim sbcmbbannedplayers As New StringBuilder()

    For Each item As Object In cmbbannedplayers.Items
        sbcmbbannedplayers.AppendFormat("{0} {1}", item, Environment.NewLine)

        Dim cmbbannedplayerssave As String = root + "\banned-players.txt"
        If System.IO.File.Exists(cmbbannedplayerssave) = True Then
        Else
            System.IO.File.Create(cmbbannedplayerssave).Dispose()
        End If
        Dim bannedplayersWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(cmbbannedplayerssave)
        bannedplayersWriter.Write(sbcmbbannedplayers.ToString()) 'Use the stringbuilder here
        bannedplayersWriter.WriteLine()
        bannedplayersWriter.Close()
    Next

    Dim sbcmbbannedips As New StringBuilder()

    For Each item As Object In cmbbannedips.Items
        sbcmbbannedips.AppendFormat("{0} {1}", item, Environment.NewLine)

        Dim cmbbannedipssave As String = root + "\banned-ips.txt"
        If System.IO.File.Exists(cmbbannedipssave) = True Then
        Else
            System.IO.File.Create(cmbbannedipssave).Dispose()
        End If
        Dim bannedipsWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(cmbbannedipssave)
        bannedipsWriter.Write(sbcmbbannedips.ToString()) 'Use the stringbuilder here
        bannedipsWriter.WriteLine()
        bannedipsWriter.Close()
    Next

    Dim sbcmbops As New StringBuilder()

    For Each item As Object In cmbops.Items
        sbcmbops.AppendFormat("{0} {1}", item, Environment.NewLine)

        Dim cmbopssave As String = root + "\ops.txt"
        If System.IO.File.Exists(cmbopssave) = True Then
        Else
            System.IO.File.Create(cmbopssave).Dispose()
        End If
        Dim opsWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(cmbopssave)
        opsWriter.Write(sbcmbops.ToString()) 'Use the stringbuilder here
        opsWriter.WriteLine()
        opsWriter.Close()
    Next

    Dim sbcmbwhitelist As New StringBuilder()

    For Each item As Object In cmbwhitelist.Items
        sbcmbwhitelist.AppendFormat("{0} {1}", item, Environment.NewLine)

        Dim cmbwhitelistsave As String = root + "\white-list.txt"
        If System.IO.File.Exists(cmbwhitelistsave) = True Then
        Else
            System.IO.File.Create(cmbwhitelistsave).Dispose()
        End If
        Dim whitelistWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(cmbwhitelistsave)
        whitelistWriter.Write(sbcmbwhitelist.ToString()) 'Use the stringbuilder here
        whitelistWriter.WriteLine()
        whitelistWriter.Close()
    Next

    If System.IO.File.Exists(root + "\server.properties") = True Then
    Else
        System.IO.File.Create(root + "\server.properties").Dispose()
    End If
    If cmbip.Text = "Lan" Then
        cmbip.Text = ""
    End If
    If cmblevelseed.Text = "None" Then
        cmblevelseed.Text = ""
    End If
    Dim propertyWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(root + "\server.properties")
    propertyWriter.Write("#ServerCraft, Created By Bradley Smithies - Kuzon")
    propertyWriter.WriteLine("")
    propertyWriter.Write("#Minecraft server properties")
    propertyWriter.WriteLine("")
    propertyWriter.Write("#Created: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString + " at " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString)
    propertyWriter.WriteLine("")
    propertyWriter.WriteLine("")
    propertyWriter.Write("level-name=" + cmbworld.Text)
    propertyWriter.WriteLine("")
    propertyWriter.Write("allow-nether=" + allownether)
    propertyWriter.WriteLine("")
    propertyWriter.Write("view-distance=" + nudviewdistance.Text)
    propertyWriter.WriteLine("")
    propertyWriter.Write("spawn-monsters=" + spawnmonsters)
    propertyWriter.WriteLine("")
    propertyWriter.Write("online-mode=" + onlinemode)
    propertyWriter.WriteLine("")
    propertyWriter.Write("spawn-monsters=" + spawnmonsters)
    propertyWriter.WriteLine("")
    propertyWriter.Write("max-players=" + nudmaxplayers.Text)
    propertyWriter.WriteLine("")
    propertyWriter.Write("server-ip=" + cmbip.Text)
    propertyWriter.WriteLine("")
    propertyWriter.Write("pvp=" + pvp)
    propertyWriter.WriteLine("")
    propertyWriter.Write("level-seed=" + cmblevelseed.Text)
    propertyWriter.WriteLine("")
    propertyWriter.Write("server-port=" + txbseverport.Text)
    propertyWriter.WriteLine("")
    propertyWriter.Write("allow-flight=" + allowflight)
    propertyWriter.WriteLine("")
    propertyWriter.Write("white-list=" + whitelist)
    propertyWriter.WriteLine("")
    propertyWriter.Close()
    If cmbip.Text = "" Then
        cmbip.Text = "Lan"
    End If
    If cmblevelseed.Text = "" Then
        cmblevelseed.Text = "None"
    End If
    If cbxlaunch.Checked Then
        Dim serverpath As String
        If cmbserverapplication.Text = "Jar Server" Then
            If System.IO.File.Exists(serverfile) = True Then
                If Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem = True Then
                    bit = "64"
                Else
                    bit = "32"
                End If
                Dim javapath As String
                Dim launchcode As String
                If bit = 64 Then
                    If System.IO.File.Exists("C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe") = True Then
                        javapath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe"
                    Else
                        javapath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe"
                    End If
                Else
                    If System.IO.File.Exists("C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe") = True Then
                        javapath = "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe"
                    Else
                        javapath = "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe"
                    End If
                End If
                launchcode = "-Xmx" + nudram.Value + "M -Xms" + nudram.Value + "M -jar " + safeserverfile + " nogui"
                ' Dim pi As New ProcessStartInfo(javapath)
                ' pi.Arguments = launchcode
                ' Process.Start(pi)
                Dim jarbatchserver As String = (root + "\runbjarbatchserver.bat")
                If System.IO.File.Exists(jarbatchserver) = True Then
                Else
                    System.IO.File.Create(jarbatchserver).Dispose()
                End If
                Dim jarbatchwriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(jarbatchserver)
                If cbxechooff.Checked = True Then
                    jarbatchwriter.Write("@ECHO OFF")
                    jarbatchwriter.WriteLine("")
                End If
                jarbatchwriter.Write("""" + javapath + """" + " " + launchcode)
                jarbatchwriter.WriteLine("")
                jarbatchwriter.Write("pause")
                jarbatchwriter.WriteLine("")
                jarbatchwriter.Close()
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(jarbatchserver)
                Me.Close()

            Else
                MsgBox("The server file does not exist. Please make sure that you have select the right file type and that it has not been renamed.")
            End If

        ElseIf cmbserverapplication.Text = "Exe Server" Then

            If System.IO.File.Exists(serverfile) = True Then
                Dim startInfo As System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
                Dim pStart As New System.Diagnostics.Process
                startInfo = New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(serverfile)
                pStart.StartInfo = startInfo
                pStart.Start()
                Me.Close()
            Else
                MsgBox("The server file does not exist. Please make sure that you have select the right file type and that it has not been renamed.")
            End If
        ElseIf cmbserverapplication.Text = "Bukkit Server" Then
            If System.IO.File.Exists(serverfile) = True Then
                If Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem = True Then
                    bit = "64"
                Else
                    bit = "32"
                End If
                serverpath = "craftbukkit-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
                Dim javapath As String
                If bit = 64 Then
                    If System.IO.File.Exists("C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe") = True Then
                        javapath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe"
                    Else
                        javapath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe"
                    End If
                Else
                    If System.IO.File.Exists("C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe") = True Then
                        javapath = "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe"
                    Else
                        javapath = "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe"
                    End If
                End If
                Dim bukkitbatchserver As String = (root + "\runbukkitbatchserver.bat")
                If System.IO.File.Exists(bukkitbatchserver) = True Then
                Else
                    System.IO.File.Create(bukkitbatchserver).Dispose()
                End If
                Dim bukkitbatchwriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(bukkitbatchserver)
                If cbxechooff.Checked = True Then
                    bukkitbatchwriter.Write("@ECHO OFF")
                    bukkitbatchwriter.WriteLine("")
                End If
                bukkitbatchwriter.Write("SET BINDIR=%~dp0")
                bukkitbatchwriter.WriteLine("")
                bukkitbatchwriter.Write("CD /D ""%BINDIR%""")
                bukkitbatchwriter.WriteLine("")
                bukkitbatchwriter.Write("""" + javapath + """" + " -Xincgc -Xmx1G -jar " + safeserverfile)
                bukkitbatchwriter.WriteLine("")
                bukkitbatchwriter.Write("pause")
                bukkitbatchwriter.Close()
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(bukkitbatchserver)
                Me.Close()
            Else
                MsgBox("The server file does not exist. Please make sure that you have select the right file type and that it has not been renamed.")
            End If

        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("Properties Changed")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btnaddworld_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnaddworld.Click
    If Not cmbworld.Text = "" Then
        cmbworld.Items.Add(cmbworld.Text)
        cmbworld.Text = ""
    End If
    For i As Int16 = 0 To Me.cmbworld.Items.Count - 2
        For j As Int16 = Me.cmbworld.Items.Count - 1 To i + 1 Step -1
            If Me.cmbworld.Items(i).ToString = Me.cmbworld.Items(j).ToString Then
                Me.cmbworld.Items.RemoveAt(j)
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub btnremoveworld_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnremoveworld.Click
    cmbworld.Items.Remove(cmbworld.Text)
    cmbworld.Text = ""
End Sub
Private Sub btnaddip_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnaddip.Click
    If Not cmbip.Text = "" Then
        cmbip.Items.Add(cmbip.Text)
        cmbip.Text = ""
    End If
    For i As Int16 = 0 To Me.cmbip.Items.Count - 2
        For j As Int16 = Me.cmbip.Items.Count - 1 To i + 1 Step -1
            If Me.cmbip.Items(i).ToString = Me.cmbip.Items(j).ToString Then
                Me.cmbip.Items.RemoveAt(j)
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub btnremoveip_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnremoveip.Click
    If Not cmbip.Text = "Lan" Then
        cmbip.Items.Remove(cmbip.Text)
        cmbip.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub btnaddlevelseed_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnaddlevelseed.Click
    If Not cmblevelseed.Text = "" Then
        cmblevelseed.Items.Add(cmblevelseed.Text)
        cmblevelseed.Text = ""
        For i As Int16 = 0 To Me.cmblevelseed.Items.Count - 2
            For j As Int16 = Me.cmblevelseed.Items.Count - 1 To i + 1 Step -1
                If Me.cmblevelseed.Items(i).ToString = Me.cmblevelseed.Items(j).ToString Then
                    Me.cmblevelseed.Items.RemoveAt(j)
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnremovelevelseed_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnremovelevelseed.Click
    If Not cmbip.Text = "none" Then
        cmblevelseed.Items.Remove(cmblevelseed.Text)
        cmblevelseed.Text = ""
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub cbxwhitelist_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cbxwhitelist.CheckedChanged
    If cbxwhitelist.Checked Then
        lblwhitelist.Visible = True
        cmbwhitelist.Visible = True
        btnaddwhitelist.Visible = True
        btnremovewhitelist.Visible = True
    Else
        lblwhitelist.Visible = False
        cmbwhitelist.Visible = False
        btnaddwhitelist.Visible = False
        btnremovewhitelist.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnaddbannedplayers_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnaddbannedplayers.Click
    If Not cmbbannedplayers.Text = "" Then
        cmbbannedplayers.Items.Add(cmbbannedplayers.Text)
        cmbbannedplayers.Text = ""
        For i As Int16 = 0 To Me.cmbbannedplayers.Items.Count - 2
            For j As Int16 = Me.cmbbannedplayers.Items.Count - 1 To i + 1 Step -1
                If Me.cmbbannedplayers.Items(i).ToString = Me.cmbbannedplayers.Items(j).ToString Then
                    Me.cmbbannedplayers.Items.RemoveAt(j)
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnremovebannedplayers_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnremovebannedplayers.Click
    cmbbannedplayers.Items.Remove(cmbbannedplayers.Text)
    cmbbannedplayers.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub btnaddbannedips_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnaddbannedips.Click
    If Not cmbbannedips.Text = "" Then
        cmbbannedips.Items.Add(cmbbannedips.Text)
        cmbbannedips.Text = ""
        For i As Int16 = 0 To Me.cmbbannedips.Items.Count - 2
            For j As Int16 = Me.cmbbannedips.Items.Count - 1 To i + 1 Step -1
                If Me.cmbbannedips.Items(i).ToString = Me.cmbbannedips.Items(j).ToString Then
                    Me.cmbbannedips.Items.RemoveAt(j)
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub lblremovebannedips_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lblremovebannedips.Click
    cmbbannedips.Items.Remove(cmbbannedips.Text)
    cmbbannedips.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub btnaddops_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnaddops.Click
    If Not cmbops.Text = "" Then
        cmbops.Items.Add(cmbops.Text)
        cmbops.Text = ""
        For i As Int16 = 0 To Me.cmbops.Items.Count - 2
            For j As Int16 = Me.cmbops.Items.Count - 1 To i + 1 Step -1
                If Me.cmbops.Items(i).ToString = Me.cmbops.Items(j).ToString Then
                    Me.cmbops.Items.RemoveAt(j)
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnremoveops_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnremoveops.Click
    cmbops.Items.Remove(cmbops.Text)
    cmbops.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub btnaddwhitelist_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnaddwhitelist.Click
    If Not cmbwhitelist.Text = "" Then
        cmbwhitelist.Items.Add(cmbwhitelist.Text)
        cmbwhitelist.Text = ""
        For i As Int16 = 0 To Me.cmbwhitelist.Items.Count - 2
            For j As Int16 = Me.cmbwhitelist.Items.Count - 1 To i + 1 Step -1
                If Me.cmbwhitelist.Items(i).ToString = Me.cmbwhitelist.Items(j).ToString Then
                    Me.cmbwhitelist.Items.RemoveAt(j)
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnremovewhitelist_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnremovewhitelist.Click
    cmbwhitelist.Items.Remove(cmbwhitelist.Text)
    cmbwhitelist.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub cmbip_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbip.SelectedIndexChanged
    If cmbip.Text = "Lan" Then
        cbxonlinemode.Checked = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub cbxonlinemode_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cbxonlinemode.CheckedChanged
    If cmbip.Text = "Lan" Then
        If cbxonlinemode.Checked Then
            cbxonlinemode.Checked = False
            MsgBox("If you would like to run your server in online mode then please enter an ip other than the Lan option")
        End If
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub txbroot_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    cmbbannedplayers.Items.Clear()
    cmbip.Items.Clear()
    cmbbannedips.Items.Clear()
    cmbops.Items.Clear()
    If File.Exists(root + "\banned-players.txt") Then
        For Each line As String In File.ReadLines(root + "\banned-players.txt")
            If line.Length <> 0 Then
                cmbbannedplayers.Items.Add(line)
            End If
        Next line
    End If

    If File.Exists(root + "\banned-ips.txt") Then
        For Each line As String In File.ReadLines(root + "\banned-ips.txt")
            If line.Length <> 0 Then
                cmbbannedips.Items.Add(line)
            End If
        Next line
    End If

    If File.Exists(root + "\ops.txt") Then
        For Each line As String In File.ReadLines(root + "\ops.txt")
            If line.Length <> 0 Then
                cmbops.Items.Add(line)
            End If
        Next line
    End If

    If File.Exists(root + "\white-list.txt") Then
        For Each line As String In File.ReadLines(root + "\white-list.txt")
            If line.Length <> 0 Then
                cmbwhitelist.Items.Add(line)
            End If
        Next line
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub btnserverfilebrowse_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnserverfilebrowse.Click
    Dim ofdserverfile As New OpenFileDialog
    'Dialog
    With ofdserverfile
        .Title = "Please Select Server File"
        ' Desktop is the root folder in the dialog.
        .InitialDirectory = root
        .Filter = filter
        ' Prompt the user with a custom message.
        root = .FileName
        If .ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            serverfile = .FileName
            safeserverfile = .SafeFileName
            txbserverfile.Text = serverfile
            root = Path.GetDirectoryName(serverfile)
        End If
    End With

End Sub
Private Sub cmbserverapplication_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbserverapplication.SelectedIndexChanged
    If cmbserverapplication.Text = "Exe Server" Then
        serverapplication = "minecraft_server.exe"
        lblram.Visible = False
        nudram.Visible = False
        filter = "Exe Server|*.exe|All Files|*.*"
    ElseIf cmbserverapplication.Text = "Jar Server" Then
        serverapplication = "minecraft_server.jar"
        lblram.Visible = True
        nudram.Visible = True
        filter = "Jar Server|*.jar|All Files|*.*"
    ElseIf cmbserverapplication.Text = "Bukkit Server" Then
        serverapplication = "craftbukkit-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
        lblram.Visible = False
        nudram.Visible = False
        filter = "Bukkit Server|*.jar|All Files|*.*"
    End If
    Dim CurrrentDirectory As String = CurDir.ToString
    If txbserverfile.Text = "" Or txbserverfile.Text = CurDir.ToString + "\minecraft_server.exe" Or txbserverfile.Text = CurDir.ToString + "\minecraft_server.jar" Or txbserverfile.Text = CurDir.ToString + "\craftbukkit-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" Then
        txbserverfile.Text = CurDir.ToString + "\" + serverapplication
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Where does the error occur? Try to isolate it, this way there's too much code to sift through.

Comment: So, where does your compiler say it happens?

Comment: Did you really need to post **all** this code. Try reducing the problem to the smallest amount of code that repeats the problem before posting.

Comment: Really hard to answer this without a lot more info, for instance what is `nudram`? It doesn't appear to be declared in this code. However a good place to start is all the numbers you have declared as strings - for instance `halfram = ((ram / "1,048,576") / "2") - "1"` should be: `halfram = ((ram / 1048576) / 2) - 1`

Comment: VB.net's pretty at dealing with conversions though, so it looks like the place to start would be where it can't, for instance `""` can't be converted to a `Double` at all - `If nudram.Value = "" Or "1024" Then` should be `If nudram.Value is Nothing OrElse nudram.Value = 1024 Then` (assuming `nudram.Value` is a `Nullable(Of Double)`)

Comment: I am sorry for posting all the code but that is to problem i only get the error when i build it and run it outside vb.net. and nudram is a numerical up down

Comment: What do you mean by "run it outside vb.net"? Is this a compiler error or a run-time one? Either way don't you get a line number?

Comment: oh yes! the line number!!!!! ok, it is once i compile it i can't get the error to repeat when i am using the debugger

Comment: @Keith what does this error mean?

Comment: The error means you're trying to assign a `String` value `""` to a `Double` variable. VB can figure this out for you if the string is a number, for instance `"1234.5"` would be ok, but VB can't convert `""` to a number - there's no equivalent number to an empty string. From your error it looks like your bug is on line 30, which I think is `If nudram.Value = "" Or "1024"`, but you've already looked into that. I'd suggest running the debugger to see what values you have when it falls over.

Comment: I can't get it to repeat in a debugger

Comment: So when you run this with the debugger attached you don't get the error or can you not get the debugger to work in the first place?

Comment: If you get the error in the build, and not in debug, delete the 3 files in your build directory the .exe the .pdb and the .xml and rebuild. Happend to me too that build did not build, and I kept executing an old version

Comment: Please be sure in the top of your code or in your project settings that you have Option Strict On

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

```
 halfram = ((ram / "1,048,576") / "2") - "1"
nudram.Maximum = halfram

If nudram.Value = "" Or "1024" Then
    nudram.Value = halfram
End If
```

code

```
 halfram = ((ram / 1048576) / 2) - 1
nudram.Maximum = halfram

If nudram.Value = 0 Or nudram.Value = 1024 Then
    nudram.Value = halfram
End If
```

But for your own sake set the option strict to ON so you declare your variables. Think of the poor guy that has to edit your source in 10 years time.

Comment: Did you change all strings, that are involved in calculations, into numbers? and did you declare ALL variabels in your program with the proper type: Dim ram, halram as integer other Dim xxxx,yyyy as String and again Dim ZZZ,AAA as Double? Did you turn Implicit off? After doing this it's hard te get into trouble! If you don't, then you'll find yourself in trouble often while executing the program. Let the compiler detect as many mistakes as possible! Go for it, I see that you're juist beginning with VB, but you may come a long way.

Answer (score 0):

try `If nudram.Value = 0 Or nudram.Value = 1024 Then`

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing "1,048,576" to "1.048.576" or use it as a number instead, just 1048576.

The decimal/thousand separator can be different on different systems, and some will interpret 1,048,576 as a million and change (`,` as thousand separator), while other will try to interpret as double (and blow up on the second decimal separator).

Comment: Try to reproduce the problem with a smaller application, a console app with few lines of code if possible. Right now, every suggestion is just poking the code with a stick in the dark, hoping we guess the problem.

Comment: I know, the problem is that i can't get the error to repeat in VB.net, i think it is because it save setting on exit. How would I reset all my setting to defult in vb.net debug?

Answer (score 0):

`If bit = 64` should be `If bit = "64"`

Comment: Still No luck :( Sorry, Thanks for the suggestion